# NavBar Hover and Current Effects

Tags: html, css

So what i want to happen is for the background of the current link(the link of the page you are currently on) to turn a seperate color and also for the font color to change to white. I also want this same effect to occur on a:hover (for links you are hovering over). I have gotten very close to this effect, however my one issue is that to change the font color of a:hover the mouse needs to be directly over the link and not simply within its container. I understand why this would not work since im giving this property to the link specifically and not the list, but font color changes for the "a" dont work if i put them with #nav li. 
The effects i want are similar to those of the NavBar on this page http://www.vitalsmarts.com/
CSS/HTML:

```
<style>

#nav{
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    height:50px;
    background-image:url("image/menuBg.png");
}

#nav li {
    float:left;
    width:155px;    
}


#nav li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:1.3em;
    color:#000000;
}

 #nav li:hover {
    background-color:#143D17;
     color:#FFFFFF;
}

 #nav li a:hover {
      color:#FFFFFF;
 }

#nav li a.currentFont {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

 .navPadS {
     padding:13px 0px;
}

 .navPadL {
     padding:13px 12px;
 }

.navPadLL {
     padding-top:13px;
     padding-bottom:13px;
     padding-right:20px;
 }

.current {
    background-color:#143D17;
 }

</style>


<body>

<!Header and NavBar>

<div id="navCont">
        <ul id="nav" class"tbBord">
            <li class="navPadS"><a class="currentFont" href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li class="navPadLL"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li class="navPadL"><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li class="navPadS"><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li class="navPadS"><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li class="navPadS"><a href="#">home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't style the li's just float them left and put all your style in the a's. I've created [this example on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/unofab/1/edit) but the bit that matters is:

```
#nav li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
    float:left;
}
#nav li a {
   text-decoration:none;
   font-size:1.3em;
   color:#000000;
   width:155px;
   display:block;
   padding:10px;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.currentFont {
    background-color:#143D17;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your css

```
#nav li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:1.3em;
    color:#000000;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Ahh i did try that and it wasn't working but since you suggested it i played around a bit with it. I will need to change the padding classes to margin with link selectors instead of basic classes (#nav li a.padding) Thanks